# context free languages closure properties

Tags: computer-science

This isn't homework.

Prove or dis-prove the statement: If $R$ is a regular language and both $L$ \ $R$ and $L \cup R$ are context-free, then $L$ is context-free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $R = A^*$, where $A$ is your alphabet.